# page title name is not showing from page source after changing the page title using java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

my page title like this
`<title></title>.`
i have changed the page title using javascript by using this code..

```
document.title = 'my desired title';
```

it is working fine it shows pagetitle at the right place but when i opening the viewsource the pagetitle is not showing it remains blank like this

```
<title></title>
```

i also tried to set a id of a title like this

```
<title id="titlename"></title>
```

and i write javascript to change the title..Here is my code
    $(titlename).html("my desired title");

but same problem occuring means page title is changing but title name is not showing at viewsource..
i want something like this
my desired title
but i am getting  when i opening viewsource..how to solve this problem??can anyone help me please??
i am using asp.net mvc

Comment: Hit F12 or right-click and "inspect" in Chrome to see changes. view-source never changes.

Comment: but if pagetitle will not come then it is a big problem for seo

Comment: how to solve this??

Comment: Google may execute the JS and add it to SEO. If you need the title to be static, make it static. Serve the title correctly from the beginning

Answer (score 1):

View source is a static snapshot of the document as it was delivered by the server. Try using the developer tools of your browser to see dynamic changes to the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Sorry but i don't understand what u are trying to say..can you explain me in details???

Comment: Did you down vote because you didn't understand me? What you are seeing when you view source is the response fro the server. Any changes you make to that response are not shown in this view. You need to inspect the page using your browsers developer tools if you want to see changes you have made.